# The ios simulators doesn't show in my XamarinForms project

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I can't test my ios application in visual studio 2017, Windows 10. I managed to connect to my mac from VS. I installed XCode 9.4.1 on the mac. The osx version is 10.13.4 High Sierra.

Restarted both machines as well.

In the Info.plist file the Deployment target is 11.0. I tried to set it to 10 but does't help.

Why the simulators doesn't show in the list?
Many thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KPG7.png)

Comment: Finally I managed to solve this issue by updating vs2017 to the newest version. Everything is ok now.

Thanks

Comment: been there too! here is a thing, update sequence should be: VS -> Xamarin -> MacOs -> XCode